# Can a member operator be used without referring to the "this" pointer?

Tags: c++

I would like to overload the `[] operator` and use it within a member function without referring to the `this` pointer, because the point of overloading, at least in this case, is brevity. I don't think it can be done, can it? It seems inconsistent that I can access member functions without dereferencing `this`, but not member operators.

```
#include <iostream>

struct demo {
  int i;

  void operator [](demo d) {
    std::cout << "operator called [" << d.i << "]" << std::endl;
  }

  void run() {

    demo k = { 5 };

    (*this)[k] ;          // works
    this->operator[](k);  // works
    // [k]                // fails - why?    
  }

};
```

Comment: If you added `void operator+(int x) {...}`, would you expect `+1;` in a method to call your overloaded operator too? :P

Comment: Unrelated: Don't overload operators for brevity. Overload them for readability. If readability and brevity happen to overlap, cool beans. If not, you'll find you saved time writing and spent more time debugging and maintaining. And debugging and maintaining are where the real time costs are.

Comment: @user4581301 brevity improves readability here - putting "this" everywhere is just visually distracting

Comment: you can call `k[k]` for example. What are you actually trying to achieve? When `run` is no member function your "problem" is gone

Comment: I'm no friend of the `this` everywhere style of coding, but in this case you're kind of screwed. `(*this)[k];` is the briefest you can get. My above comment's not aimed at the perfectly reasonable overloading of `[]` for a container, but for the folk who decide to write cryptic code by overloading operators with wild and surprising results simply to save a few keystrokes. Then some poor bugger comes along later and tries to reason why their predecessor was trying to add two bananas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use it without `this` like

```
operator[](k);
```

Comment: You did answer the title question, but the more general question was about using abbreviated/readable syntax and the inconsistency of needing to use "this". It seems the answer is "no, not possible".

Answer (score 3):

Just writing `[k];` is simply syntactically incorrect in C++. Why? Maybe because no one though to make it a feature, it is pretty niche and not really readable.

In post-C++11 it is most likely parsed as a lambda with missing body, that is why a compiler complains about expected `{`. For example `[k]{return k;};` is a correct lambda definition.